# Access and update class property value from user control c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have user control called UCPlayerAccount in where I have created "model", an instance of class PersonModel, and populated it with values.
Now, in UCPlayerAccount i have button that loads another user control, let's say it is called UCX, with it's own logic for creating some tasks for user. When user confirm's answers, I want to sum points with value from model.Points property, but in UCX I cannot access "model" instance as it is from the previous user control, that is from UCPlayerAccount.
I'm using C# Windows Form.
This is my class PersonModel:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public int CurrLevel { get; set; }
    public int CurrClass { get; set; }
    public List<AvatarPicture> Avatars { get; set; } = new List<AvatarPicture>();

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return $"{ FirstName } { LastName }"; }
    }
}
```

How to access "model" in UCX, can anyone help?

Comment: You can add a Public Property (or Public Method) in UCX, which is set by `model` when it creates UCX. You can pass the current `Points` value to UCX this way. Or pass the `PersonModel` instance to UCX when it creates an instance of it. In this case, UCX must *know about the existence* of the `PersonModel` class, which is not exactly *good*, but not *terrible*. It depends on how many *principles* you're willing to break :)

Comment: Ok, in UCX I added public PersonModel model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { model = value; }
        } , now it throws me System.StackOverflowExeption on get {return model;} part

Comment: Yes, quite probable :) Use the other method: add `public int ModelPoints { get; set; }` to the UCX class. Then, when `model` creates UCX, set the property with the current value: `var ucx = new UCX(); ucx.ModelPoints = this.Points;`. When, in UCX, you need this value, read `ModelPoints`.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much, this saved my very hard day! One virtual beer for you!